# Getting a pulsing SVG to work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have an SVG that pulses and it works in most browsers except IE.

How would I be able to get this working in IE without resorting to an animated GIF?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGyif)

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="179.734px" height="179.736px" viewBox="0 0 179.734 179.736" enable-background="new 0 0 179.734 179.736"
     xml:space="preserve">

    <g transform="translate(80,80)">
        <g id="pulse_2">
            <path opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M120.864,99.676c0,11.599-9.401,21-21,21c-11.598,0-21-9.401-21-21c0-11.598,9.402-21,21-21c6.705,0,12.679,3.144,16.523,8.037C119.193,90.281,120.864,94.783,120.864,99.676z" transform="translate( -100 -100)" />
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="0s" from="0" by="2" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            <animate attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill-opacity" from="0" to="0" values="0;0.5;0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="centre">
        <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="10" stroke="#fff" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How are you inserting the svg in your document? (img, object, inline)

Answer (score 2):

IE does not support SMIL (i.e. the animae and animateTransform tags). There is a javascript shim called [fakeSmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/) that can be used to give IE this functionality.